# WordPress in a sub directory but not images

Tags: directory, uploads

I have followed this tutorial [from WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and managed to get everything to work. I have installed WordPress in a subfolder called `/wordpress`.

The problem that the images I uploaded show the `/wordpress` directory name in the URL. Can that be removed without moving the uploads folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Settings > Media*. Enter the option *Full URL path to files* according to the file structure on you server.